# How to build a list in a word file with docxtemplater?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docxtemplater

My template file (i.e. template.docx) is shown as the following:

[image]

My node.js code:

```
let Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let PizZip = require('pizzip');
let content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'template.docx'), 'binary');
let zip = new PizZip(content);
let doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { paragraphLoop: true, linebreaks: true });

let statData = {items:[{"name":"item 1","desc":"xxx\nyyyy" },{"name":"item 2","desc":"www\njjj"}]};
doc.setData(statData);
doc.render();
let buf = doc.getZip().generate({ type: 'nodebuffer' });
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'output.docx'), but);
```

I expected the resultant word file should be as below:

[image]

However, the actual result is something like below:

[image]

I have created a list in the "item description" cell.

However, the actual result does not work as my expectation.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data you have :

```
{
  items: [
    { name: "item 1", desc: "xxx\nyyyy" },
    { name: "item 2", desc: "www\njjj" },
  ];
}
```

And in your template, you use :

```
- {desc}
```

This will indeed just add a newline to the list, not create a new list item.

To create a new list item, I would change the structure to this :

```
{
  items: [
    { name: "item 1", desc: ["xxx", "yyyy"] },
    { name: "item 2", desc: ["www", "jjj"] },
  ];
}
```

And in your template :

```
- {-w:p desc}{.}{/}
```

This can also be tested online with this demo : https://docxtemplater.com/demo/#loop-list

Comment: I have tried your syntax, it does not work on my side. The correct syntax should be:

- {-w:p desc}{.}{/desc}{/items}

Comment: Yes, right, the full code should be : 

`| {items} |   {-w:p desc}{.}{/desc}{/items} |`